# How to work out the constant and mean of the function?

Tags: probability, statistics, functions

I am getting ready for the midterm test and in one of the old exams I found this problem:

Can someone solve this one for me please?

Let X be a random variable with probability function $$f(x) = cx^2$$x = 1, 2, . . . , n.

I need to find the constant c so that f(x) is a valid probability function, and then show that the mean of X is: $$E(X)=\frac {3n(n+1)}{2(2n+1)}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. 

You've already had 2 questions closed for similar reasons; please [edit] your post to improve it as needed.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 type your question rather than providing link. Also include your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $f$ is a probability function $ \iff c \sum_{k=1}^n k^2=1$
2. $E(X)=c \sum_{k=1}^n k^3$

Your turn !

Comment: 1. $c*\frac {n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}=1$ ? Am I on the right path?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right path

Comment: Thanks Fred. Why in 2. do I need the sum of cubed integers? Why cubed?

Comment: Recall the definition of $E(X)$ !

Comment: Yup, got it! Thank you so much, Fred!